# Calculating template page numbers

Tags: c#, .net

I have a function which sets the text to a label displaying current active "products" and current active pages. The label displays "X products, Y pages/page" depending on the amount of products active in the template. Products is the same as rows really, the client wants to call it products.

The template consists of a number of tags, `activeTags`, which holds the tags that are not deleted. One row consists of a number of tags, perhaps 2 or 3, in the property `_selectedTemplateConfiguration.TemplateConfigurationTagsPerRow`. Every template page can hold a number of products/rows, `_selectedTemplateConfiguration.TemplateConfigurationRowsPerPage`.

Let's say I have 41 rows and the template takes 20 rows on each page. This means I have 3 pages active. When I made the function I could not get it to work without the use of the `divisionRest`variable, ie. when I had 40 rows it still said it was 3 active pages, due to `Math.Ceiling`.

The `_currentTagCollection`consists really of a number of Telerik RadDocks with a text input, the idea with the whole template is that the client can enter textvalues into a template online, which is the printed.

I probably missed something, but this is a function that I feel could be made different. Feel free to ask if I need to clarify anything. I'm using .NET 4.0.

[image]

```
private string displayTemplateNumbers()
{
  int totalPagesActive;
  var activeTags = _currentTagCollection.Count - totalAmountOfDeletedTags();

  var divisionRest = (Convert.ToDouble(activeTags / _selectedTemplateConfiguration.TemplateConfigurationTagsPerRow) % _selectedTemplateConfiguration.TemplateConfigurationRowsPerPage);

  if (divisionRest == 0) //Math.Ceiling thinks it's 3 pages when it's only 2, have to check divisionRest like this
  {
       totalPagesActive = Convert.ToInt32((activeTags / _selectedTemplateConfiguration.TemplateConfigurationRowsPerPage) / _selectedTemplateConfiguration.TemplateConfigurationTagsPerRow);
  }
  else
  {
       totalPagesActive = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((Convert.ToDouble(activeTags) / Convert.ToDouble(_selectedTemplateConfiguration.TemplateConfigurationRowsPerPage)) / Convert.ToDouble(_selectedTemplateConfiguration.TemplateConfigurationTagsPerRow)).ToString());
  }
  var pages =  totalPagesActive > 1 ? string.Format("{0} pages", totalPagesActive) : string.Format("{0} page", 1);
  return string.Format("{0} products, {1}", activeTags / _selectedTemplateConfiguration.TemplateConfigurationTagsPerRow, pages);
}

private int totalAmountOfDeletedTags()
{
 int counter = 0;
 foreach (var tag in _currentTagCollection)
 {
   if (tag.Deleted)
   {
      counter++;
   }
 }
 return counter;
}
```

Comment: What version of .net are you using? What is `T` in `List<T> _currentTagCollection`? Can you please post `private int totalAmountOfDeletedTags()`

Comment: @RobertSnyder Edited my question with version and the missing function + screenshot, trying to make it a little clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue with ceiling is just misprinting.
You should call Ceiling on whole expression, not just on part.
So instead

```
totalPagesActive = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((Convert.ToDouble(activeTags) / Convert.ToDouble(_selectedTemplateConfiguration.TemplateConfigurationRowsPerPage)) / Convert.ToDouble(_selectedTemplateConfiguration.TemplateConfigurationTagsPerRow)).ToString());
```

should be

```
totalPagesActive = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((Convert.ToDouble(activeTags) / Convert.ToDouble(_selectedTemplateConfiguration.TemplateConfigurationRowsPerPage) / Convert.ToDouble(_selectedTemplateConfiguration.TemplateConfigurationTagsPerRow))).ToString());
```

and you can remove `if` blocks after this

Here is test with ceiling with your values:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/19FESY

Comment: Oh man, stupid `)`. Seems to work like a charm, thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Hm, I noticed after some tests that if I test this with your fiddle, with three variables, it does not work. Do you have any idea why that is?
https://dotnetfiddle.net/KH091J

Comment: @Magnetize, In your fiddle you again put brackets as in original sample. Try to simplify your expression in code. `totalPagesActive = (int)Math.Ceiling(((double)40) / 20 / 2);` https://dotnetfiddle.net/pZi1Ih

Comment: Hm I still dont get it though. `var test = (int)Math.Ceiling(((double)40) / 20 / 2);`should show 2 pages.
`var test = (int)Math.Ceiling(((double)41) / 20 / 2);` should show 3 pages.
Am I just doing it totally wrong? https://dotnetfiddle.net/DrJaej

Comment: @Magnetize, if there are should be 2 and 3 pages, then error in logic somewhere else. Because 40 / 20 / 2 = 1, same as 2x2=4

Comment: hm yeah, you are probably right. I think I need to double check the whole calculation. Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: Update, realised that I misled you, 40 and 41 is not active tags, it is active rows, and that is `tags/tagsPerRow`. I was trying to divide one time too much. You were right all along. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your method names do not follow capitalization standards, they should be PascalCase.

However, what's worse is that their names do not correspond to that they do:

- `displayTemplateNumbers()` returns a formatted string (and thus doesn't "display" anything),
- `totalAmountOfDeletedTags()` feels like it should be a property instead of a method.

And `totalAmountOfDeletedTags()` isn't even necessary, since it can be replaced by simple LINQ: `_currentTagCollection.Count(x => x.Deleted);`. And since you only need the active tags, you can simply do `var activeTags = _currentTagCollection.Count(x => !x.Deleted);` (h/t to @RobertSnyder).

---

At the end of `displayTemplateNumbers()` you twice call `string.Format()`. Instead you should do this once:

```
return string.Format("{0} products, {1} page{2}", 
    activeTags / _selectedTemplateConfiguration.TemplateConfigurationTagsPerRow, 
    totalPagesActive,
    (totalPagesActive > 1 ? "s" : string.Empty));
```

Comment: OP wants active tags, so `Count(x=>!x.Deleted)`

Comment: @RobertSnyder The method is called `totalAmountOfDeletedTags()` and his own logic clearly counts tags where `tag.Deleted` is true. Ah wait, I see what you mean, you're right, that line can be shorter.

Comment: @BCdotWEB thanks, this is part of a inhouse CMS that I happened to inherit. They use camelCase for private methods and PascalCase for public methods, that's why I kept it that way.
I see your point with the method names, and I thank you for the suggestions. :)